# Vue Js public Websocket blocked by CORS policy

Tags: node.js, vue.js, websocket, cors

I've created a application with Vue and Node js but I get a trouble "CORS" when I try to connect to a public websocket from "http://localhost".

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkRVS.png)

[Error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJEcw.png)

I believe the cause of this problem is a trying to connect via http to a https server.

Any idea to solve this problem in localhost ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem in this case, is to try to connect to other domain from the client side and the server do not allow "Access-Control-Allow-Origin".

The best solution for this question is follow the arquiteture of project bellow:

https://github.com/Tucsky/SignificantTrades

In resume, implement conection websocket in server side and expose a local websocket in the client side.

In my case, Node and Vue js.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing this node package named **[cors-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors-server)**  that will start a web server on a given port that will proxy any request received and add CORS headers to it.

To start the server simply call it from the command line and supply a port number

```
cors-server <port>
```

After that, any requests sent to `http://localhost:[port]` will `have Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` on the response.

e.g:

POST http://localhost:3005/http://www.google.com

Hope this helps!.

Comment: Sry, this not work forme. L am try conect to websocket api and my server is sending in header, origin localhost. This is recused from server.